# Exercise 1.12 in Tao's nonlinear dispersive equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $F$ is locally Lipschitz and has at most $x\log(x)$ growth i.e.
$$\|F(u)\|_D\leq (1+\|u\|_D)\log(2+\|u\|_D).$$
Does solution to the Cauchy problem of ODE
$$\partial_tu(t)=F(u)$$
(with some initial datum) exist classically for all time or is it possible to blow up?

Comment: is there a question mark at the end?

Comment: what is the norm D? I mean, D is an Hilbert? Banach? Sobolev?

Comment: @FeliceIandoli just $R^n$ is ok

Comment: well u is a function

Comment: didn't my answer satisfy you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let for instance $D=H^s(\mathbb{R^n})$ and $\Lambda^s=(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}$ the usual Sobolev multiplier. Then one has 
$$\partial_t(1+\|u(t)\|_s^2)=\partial_t\langle\Lambda^su(t),\Lambda^su(t)\rangle_{L^2}\leq2\|u(t)\|_s(1+\|u(t)\|_s)\log(2+\|u(t)\|_s),$$
where I have used the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality and the equation. Up to constants the r.h.s. of the latter inequality is bounded by 
$$(1+\|u(t)\|^2_s)\log(1+\|u(t)\|^2_s).$$
Now set $f(t)=1+\|u(t)\|^2_s.$ We have shown that $f(t)$ is a sub-solution of the ODE
$$y'=y\log(y),$$
whose solution is $\exp({\exp{(t+c)}})$. Therefore one has that
$$1+\|u(t)\|^2_s\leq C\exp({\exp{(t+c)}}),$$
for some constant $C$, hence the solution cannot blow-up in finite time.